# hive regex serde doesnt recognize my regex

Tags: regex, hive

I used Rubular to verify my regex:

```
(\d+)\:+(\d+)+\:+(\d+)+\:+(\d+)
```

it works perfectly fine there for following string

```
1::594::5::838984679
```

but the same doesnt work in hive:

```
create external table ratings8 (userid string, movieid string, rating string, timestamp string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = "(\d+)\:+(\d+)+\:+(\d+)+\:+(\d+)", "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s" ) LOCATION '/ratings';
```

can somebody help me out here ? what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in the string (`\\`).  The colon does not require an escape, though

```
(\\d+):+(\\d+)+:+(\\d+)+:+(\\d+)
```

It's also not necessary to have `(\\d+)+` since this is equivalent to just `\\d+`.

Comment: Not only it is not necessary, it can cause catastrophic backtracking, so I think your answer should remove them outright.

Comment: Why didnt  my regex work ? I mean, it works fine in Rubular .

Comment: @ShikhaVishwakarma Since this is Hive, the object underlying your regex is actually a Java string.  Java string treat the backslash as an escaping character, and since you actually want those backslashes to remain intact and remain part of your regex, you have to escape them (with another backslash).